# Failed to fetch swarm information from Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins, centos

I am trying to connect Jenkins agent to Master with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname $0)


java -jar swarm-client-3.9.jar -name "$(hostname)" -executors 8 -labels docker -disableSslVerification -master "http://10.0.0.6:50000" -username master1 -password 1234
```

And I get this message:

```
root@Master1[/usr/local/jenkins]_: ./swarm.sh
Mar 22, 2020 9:28:14 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client main
INFO: Client.main invoked with: [-name Master1.localdomain -executors 8 -labels docker - 
disableSslVerification -master http://10.0.0.6:50000 -username master1 -password 1234]
Mar 22, 2020 9:28:14 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
INFO: Discovering Jenkins master
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Mar 22, 2020 9:28:14 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient discoverFromMasterUrl
SEVERE: Failed to fetch swarm information from Jenkins, plugin not installed?
Mar 22, 2020 9:28:14 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
SEVERE: RetryException occurred
hudson.plugins.swarm.RetryException: Failed to fetch swarm information from Jenkins, plugin not 
installed?
    at hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient.discoverFromMasterUrl(SwarmClient.java:229)
    at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.run(Client.java:146)
    at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.main(Client.java:119)

Mar 22, 2020 9:28:14 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
INFO: Retrying in 10 seconds
```

I setted up agent port to 50000 in Jenkins and enabled TCP Agent Protocol/1,2,4.
Port is open on both servers.
If I execute curl 10.0.0.6:5000 I get:

```
Jenkins-Agent-Protocols: JNLP-connect, JNLP2-connect, JNLP4-connect, Ping
Jenkins-Version: 2.204.5
Jenkins-Session: 86f65571
Client: 10.0.0.5
Server: 10.0.0.6
Remoting-Minimum-Version: 3.14
```

Using CentOS 8 and Self-Organizing Swarm Plug-in Modules v3.18

Anyone has idea why I cannot add this agent to Jenkins server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

java -jar swarm-client-3.9.jar -name "$(hostname)" -executors 8 -labels docker -disableSslVerification -master "http://10.0.0.6:8080" -username master1 -password 1234

instead 50000 use 8080

try this it will work.. I had similar problem

Comment: how did you conclude that master is running on default port ?